# If loop with 4 outcomes

Tags: vba, excel, loops, if-statement

I need to perform an if loop. Now I know (part of) the theory and which variables I want. I just need a litlle help with the, you know, actual loop. I've outlined the situation below:

Per unique person it is possible to have several preferences (3 max). The different preferences are shown in column `BO` (row 2 and down). The columns `BV, BZ & CD` hold the Preference1 , 2 and 3. [image: Dataset]

What I'd like to have happen is: The data in column `BO` gets put in `dim ToBeFunction`. Then check if this equals the Preference in column `BV`. If so, write 1 (for pref1) to cell `A1` on `WB2`. If not, does `ToBeFunction == BZ` -> write 2 to `WB2, cellA1`. If not, `ToBeFunction==CD` -> write 3 to `WB2, cellA1`. Else put 0 in `WB2, cellA1`

If it makes it any easier, the 0-3 can be replaced by the title headers of the corresponding columns.

I hope I've made my question clear. Please ask me to clarify if not.

Thanks in advance.

Edit2: Tigregalis method

```
Sub Test12()
' NOTE: I've designed this to allow me to deal with sparse rows; i.e. when cell "BO#" is empty, don't do anything and don't increment the output row
Const StBestand = "Stambestand.xlsm"
Const Competenties = "Competenties.xlsx"

Dim WbStambestand, WbIjk As Workbook
Dim stam, comp As String
Dim PathOnly, ijk, FileOnly As String
Dim WsIjk, WsStam As Worksheet

ijk = ThisWorkbook.FullName
FileOnly = ThisWorkbook.Name
PathOnly = Left(ijk, Len(ijk) - Len(FileOnly))
stam = PathOnly & "\" & StBestand
comp = PathOnly & "\" & Competenties

Set WsIjk = ActiveSheet
Set WbIjk = ThisWorkbook
Set WbStambestand = Workbooks.Open(stam)
Set WsStam = WbStambestand.Worksheets("stambestand")

    Dim rngInput As Range, rngOutput As Range
    Dim lastRowInput As Long


With WsStam ' input data sheet; I'm using ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1) just as an example, modify it to your input workbook and input sheet
    Set rngInput = .Cells(2, "BO") ' set start of input range; I'm using column 1 so that we can refer to other columns by letter instead of number easily, because we will be working with a sparse set of columns: BO, BV, BZ, CD
    lastRowInput = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "BO").End(xlUp).Row ' get last row of input range; I'm using the Worksheet.Cells(Worksheet.Rows.Count, "BO").End(xlUp).Row method; this is used in my loop termination condition (i.e. terminate when current row > lastRowInput)
End With
Set rngOutput = WsIjk.Range("A3") ' set start of output range; I'm using ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("A2") just as an example, modify it to your output workbook, output sheet, and start of output range

Debug.Print rngInput.Value
Do Until rngInput.Row > lastRowInput ' loop termination condition

    If rngInput(, "BO").Value <> "" Then ' output condition; you could of course use any more relevant condition, or remove this check entirely (if not having to deal with sparse rows)

        Select Case rngInput(, "BO").Value ' get the value of cell "BO#"
            Case rngInput(, "BV").Value
                rngOutput.Value = 1
            Case rngInput(, "BZ").Value
                rngOutput.Value = 2
            Case rngInput(, "CD").Value
                rngOutput.Value = 3
            Case Else
                rngOutput.Value = 0
        End Select

        Set rngOutput = rngOutput(2) ' increment the output row

    End If
    Set rngInput = rngInput(2) ' always increment the input row
Loop
```

End Sub

Edit2: Vitayata method:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

Const StBestand = "Stambestand.xlsm"
Const Competenties = "Competenties.xlsx"

Dim WbStambestand, WbIjk As Workbook
Dim stam, comp As String
Dim PathOnly, ijk, FileOnly As String
Dim WsIjk, WsStam As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim rngOutput As Range

ijk = ThisWorkbook.FullName
FileOnly = ThisWorkbook.Name
PathOnly = Left(ijk, Len(ijk) - Len(FileOnly))
stam = PathOnly & "\" & StBestand
comp = PathOnly & "\" & Competenties

Set WsIjk = ActiveSheet
Set WbIjk = ThisWorkbook
Set WbStambestand = Workbooks.Open(stam)
Set WsStam = WbStambestand.Worksheets("stambestand")
LastRow = WsStam.Range("S2").End(xlDown).Row

Dim cnt As Long

Set rngOutput = WsIjk.Range("A3")
'Set rngInput = WsStam.Range("BO2")


For cnt = 2 To LastRow
    Debug.Print Range("BO" & cnt)
    'Stop 'uncomment it later
    Select Case Range("BO" & cnt).Value
        Case ("BV" & cnt)
            rngOutput = 1
        Case ("BZ" & cnt)
            rngOutput = 2
        Case ("CD" & cnt)
            rngOutput = 3
        Case Else
            rngOutput = 0
    End Select

 Set rngOutput = rngOutput(2) ' increment the output row
 'Set rngInput = rngInput(2)

Next cnt
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited: removed my original answer, addressing issues with asker's implementation based on my original answer

## The problem

Refer to the second line in the following blocks.

You have:

```
    With WsStam ' input data sheet; I'm using ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1) just as an example, modify it to your input workbook and input sheet
        Set rngInput = .Cells(2, "BO") ' set start of input range; I'm using column 1 so that we can refer to other columns by letter instead of number easily, because we will be working with a sparse set of columns: BO, BV, BZ, CD
        lastRowInput = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "BO").End(xlUp).Row ' get last row of input range; I'm using the Worksheet.Cells(Worksheet.Rows.Count, "BO").End(xlUp).Row method; this is used in my loop termination condition (i.e. terminate when current row > lastRowInput)
    End With
```

I have:

```
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1) ' input data sheet; I'm using ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1) just as an example, modify it to your input workbook and input sheet
        Set rngInput = .Cells(2, 1) ' set start of input range; I'm using column 1 so that we can refer to other columns by letter instead of number easily, because we will be working with a sparse set of columns: BO, BV, BZ, CD
        lastRowInput = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "BO").End(xlUp).Row ' get last row of input range; I'm using the Worksheet.Cells(Worksheet.Rows.Count, "BO").End(xlUp).Row method; this is used in my loop termination condition (i.e. terminate when current row > lastRowInput)
    End With
```

Your input range is initialising to cell "BO2". My input range is initialising to cell "A2" (this is by design). I'll explain.

When you call `rngInput(, "BO")`, what this does is get the cell *relative* to `rngInput`.

- The first parameter is the relative row, in this example it is empty, so this means "same row as `rngInput`".
- The second parameter is the relative column. In this example it is "BO"; so does this mean "column BO"? Not necessarily It is the relative column. I'll explain with an example.

Using the Immediate Window:

```
?Range("A2")(,"BO").Address
$BO$2

?Range("BO2")(,"BO").Address
$EC$2
```

Why? The returned range is *relative* to the input range, and the parameters are the *relative* increment (if >=1) or decrement (if <=0) for the rows and columns. Excel stores certain keys as aliases of numbers, when used in the Range function: `"BO"` is effectively an alias for the number `67` (67th column), `"BV"` is `74`, `"BZ"` is `78`, `"CD"` is `82`.

## The solutions

You have a number of options, and it depends on your coding style, requirements and other factors.

### 1 Set start `rngInput` to `Sheet.Cells(2, 1)` or `Sheet.Range("A2")`

This is my example.

```
Sub TestOptionOne()
' Option one: input data is relative to column 1
' NOTE: I've designed this to allow me to deal with sparse rows; i.e. when cell "BO#" is empty, don't do anything and don't increment the output row
    Const StBestand = "Stambestand.xlsm"
    Const Competenties = "Competenties.xlsx"

    Dim WbStambestand As Workbook, WbIjk As Workbook
    Dim stam As String, comp As String
    Dim PathOnly As String, ijk As String, FileOnly As String
    Dim WsIjk As Worksheet, WsStam As Worksheet

    ijk = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    FileOnly = ThisWorkbook.Name
    PathOnly = Left(ijk, Len(ijk) - Len(FileOnly))
    stam = PathOnly & "\" & StBestand
    comp = PathOnly & "\" & Competenties

    Set WsIjk = ActiveSheet
    Set WbIjk = ThisWorkbook
    Set WbStambestand = Workbooks.Open(stam)
    Set WsStam = WbStambestand.Worksheets("stambestand")

    Dim rngInput As Range, rngOutput As Range
    Dim lastRowInput As Long

    With WsStam ' input data sheet; I'm using ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1) just as an example, modify it to your input workbook and input sheet
        Set rngInput = .Cells(2, 1) ' set start of input range to A2; I'm using column 1 so that we can refer to other columns by letter instead of number easily, because we will be working with a sparse set of columns: BO, BV, BZ, CD
        lastRowInput = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "BO").End(xlUp).Row ' get last row of input range in column BO; I'm using the Worksheet.Cells(Worksheet.Rows.Count, "BO").End(xlUp).Row method; this is used in my loop termination condition (i.e. terminate when current row > lastRowInput)
    End With
    Set rngOutput = WsIjk.Range("A3") ' set start of output range; I'm using ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("A2") just as an example, modify it to your output workbook, output sheet, and start of output range

    Debug.Print rngInput.Value
    Do Until rngInput.Row > lastRowInput ' loop termination condition

        If rngInput(, "BO").Value <> "" Then ' output condition; you could of course use any more relevant condition, or remove this check entirely (if not having to deal with sparse rows)

            Select Case rngInput(, "BO").Value ' get the value of cell "BO#"
                Case rngInput(, "BV").Value ' compare against the value of cell "BV#"
                    rngOutput.Value = 1
                Case rngInput(, "BZ").Value ' compare against the value of cell "BZ#"
                    rngOutput.Value = 2
                Case rngInput(, "CD").Value ' compare against the value of cell "CD#"
                    rngOutput.Value = 3
                Case Else
                    rngOutput.Value = 0
            End Select

            Set rngOutput = rngOutput(2) ' increment the output row

        End If
        Set rngInput = rngInput(2) ' always increment the input row
    Loop

End Sub
```

### 2 Set start `rngInput` to `Sheet.Cells(2, "BO")` or `Sheet.Range("BO2")`

You will need to determine the relative "displacement" of each input range, e.g. looking at column BV (74) relative to BZ (67), it is column 8 (74-67+1).

```
Sub TestOptionTwo()
' Option two: input data is relative to column BO
' NOTE: I've designed this to allow me to deal with sparse rows; i.e. when cell "BO#" is empty, don't do anything and don't increment the output row
    Const StBestand = "Stambestand.xlsm"
    Const Competenties = "Competenties.xlsx"

    Dim WbStambestand As Workbook, WbIjk As Workbook
    Dim stam As String, comp As String
    Dim PathOnly As String, ijk As String, FileOnly As String
    Dim WsIjk As Worksheet, WsStam As Worksheet

    ijk = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    FileOnly = ThisWorkbook.Name
    PathOnly = Left(ijk, Len(ijk) - Len(FileOnly))
    stam = PathOnly & "\" & StBestand
    comp = PathOnly & "\" & Competenties

    Set WsIjk = ActiveSheet
    Set WbIjk = ThisWorkbook
    Set WbStambestand = Workbooks.Open(stam)
    Set WsStam = WbStambestand.Worksheets("stambestand")

    Dim rngInput As Range, rngOutput As Range
    Dim lastRowInput As Long

    With WsStam ' input data sheet; I'm using ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1) just as an example, modify it to your input workbook and input sheet
        Set rngInput = .Range("B2") ' set start of input range to BO2; we will need to refer to the relative columns
        lastRowInput = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "BO").End(xlUp).Row ' get last row of input range in column BO; I'm using the Worksheet.Cells(Worksheet.Rows.Count, "BO").End(xlUp).Row method; this is used in my loop termination condition (i.e. terminate when current row > lastRowInput)
    End With
    Set rngOutput = WsIjk.Range("A3") ' set start of output range; I'm using ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("A2") just as an example, modify it to your output workbook, output sheet, and start of output range

    Debug.Print rngInput.Value
    Do Until rngInput.Row > lastRowInput ' loop termination condition

        'BO = 67 (absolute column no.); BO vs BO = 67 - 67 + 1 = 1 (column no. relative to BO)
        'BV = 74 (absolute column no.); BV vs BO = 74 - 67 + 1 = 8 (column no. relative to BO)
        'BZ = 78 (absolute column no.); BZ vs BO = 74 - 67 + 1 = 12 (column no. relative to BO)
        'CD = 82 (absolute column no.); CD vs BO = 82 - 67 + 1 = 16 (column no. relative to BO)

        If rngInput(, 1).Value <> "" Then ' output condition; you could of course use any more relevant condition, or remove this check entirely (if not having to deal with sparse rows)

            Select Case rngInput(, 1).Value ' get the value of cell "BO#"
                Case rngInput(, 8).Value ' compare against the value of cell "BV#"
                    rngOutput.Value = 1
                Case rngInput(, 12).Value ' compare against the value of cell "BZ#"
                    rngOutput.Value = 2
                Case rngInput(, 16).Value ' compare against the value of cell "CD#"
                    rngOutput.Value = 3
                Case Else
                    rngOutput.Value = 0
            End Select

            Set rngOutput = rngOutput(2) ' increment the output row

        End If
        Set rngInput = rngInput(2) ' always increment the input row
    Loop

End Sub
```

Choose this method if you prefer to work with numbers. It is most succinct, and the approach I would normally take.

### 3 Have multiple `rngInput*`s for each column

This might be easiest to understand. You will need to load each `rngInput*` variable separately and increment each `rngInput*` variable in sync.

```
Sub TestOptionThree()
' Option three: each input is manipulated independently
' NOTE: I've designed this to allow me to deal with sparse rows; i.e. when cell "BO#" is empty, don't do anything and don't increment the output row
    Const StBestand = "Stambestand.xlsm"
    Const Competenties = "Competenties.xlsx"

    Dim WbStambestand As Workbook, WbIjk As Workbook
    Dim stam As String, comp As String
    Dim PathOnly As String, ijk As String, FileOnly As String
    Dim WsIjk As Worksheet, WsStam As Worksheet

    ijk = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    FileOnly = ThisWorkbook.Name
    PathOnly = Left(ijk, Len(ijk) - Len(FileOnly))
    stam = PathOnly & "\" & StBestand
    comp = PathOnly & "\" & Competenties

    Set WsIjk = ActiveSheet
    Set WbIjk = ThisWorkbook
    Set WbStambestand = Workbooks.Open(stam)
    Set WsStam = WbStambestand.Worksheets("stambestand")

    Dim rngInput As Range, rngOutput As Range
    Dim lastRowInput As Long

    Dim rngInputPrefSelected As Range, rngInputPref1 As Range, rngInputPref2 As Range, rngInputPref3 As Range, rngOutput As Range

    With WsStam ' input data sheet; I'm using ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1) just as an example, modify it to your input workbook and input sheet
        Set rngInputPrefSelected = .Range("BO2") ' set start of input range for selected preference to BO2
        Set rngInputPref1 = .Range("BV2") ' set start of input range for preference 1 to BV2
        Set rngInputPref2 = .Range("BZ2") ' set start of input range for preference 2 to BZ2
        Set rngInputPref3 = .Range("CD2") ' set start of input range for preference 3 to CD2
        lastRowInput = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "BO").End(xlUp).Row ' get last row of input range in column BO; I'm using the Worksheet.Cells(Worksheet.Rows.Count, "BO").End(xlUp).Row method; this is used in my loop termination condition (i.e. terminate when current row > lastRowInput)
    End With
    Set rngOutput = WsIjk.Range("A3") ' set start of output range; I'm using ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("A2") just as an example, modify it to your output workbook, output sheet, and start of output range

    Debug.Print rngInputPrefSelected.Value, rngInputPref1.Value, rngInputPref2.Value, rngInputPref3.Value
    Do Until rngInput.Row > lastRowInput ' loop termination condition

        If rngInputPrefSelected.Value <> "" Then ' output condition; you could of course use any more relevant condition, or remove this check entirely (if not having to deal with sparse rows)

            Select Case rngInputPrefSelected ' get the value of cell "BO#"
                Case rngInputPref1.Value ' compare against the value of cell "BV#"
                    rngOutput.Value = 1
                Case rngInputPref2.Value ' compare against the value of cell "BZ#"
                    rngOutput.Value = 2
                Case rngInputPref3.Value ' compare against the value of cell "CD#"
                    rngOutput.Value = 3
                Case Else
                    rngOutput.Value = 0
            End Select

            Set rngOutput = rngOutput(2) ' increment the output row

        End If

        'always increment the input row
        Set rngInputPrefSelected = rngInputPrefSelected(2) ' move to next row for selected preference
        Set rngInputPref1 = rngInputPref1(2) ' move to next row for preference 1
        Set rngInputPref2 = rngInputPref3(2) ' move to next row for preference 2
        Set rngInputPref3 = rngInputPref2(2) ' move to next row for preference 3
    Loop

End Sub
```

The advantage of this method is that there is very little hard-coded. The disadvantage is that it is also more verbose.

### 4 Get a range reference to rows and columns every time

Store the row number as a `Long` variable. When looping, increment the row number (`row = row + 1`). When comparing values, always build a new Range object each time by calling `Worksheet.Cells(row, col)`; `col` will be your input column references (in this case, this is the **Absolute** row/column number or reference) which you can store as constants.

e.g. `If WsStam.Cells(row, 67) = WsStam.Cells(row, 74) Then` or `If WsStam.Cells(row, "BO") = WsStam.Cells(row, "BV") Then` or `If WsStam.Cells(row, colSelected) = WsStam.Cells(row, colPref1) Then`

```
Sub TestOptionFour()
' Rows and columns
' NOTE: I've designed this to allow me to deal with sparse rows; i.e. when cell "BO#" is empty, don't do anything and don't increment the output row
    Const StBestand = "Stambestand.xlsm"
    Const Competenties = "Competenties.xlsx"

    Dim WbStambestand As Workbook, WbIjk As Workbook
    Dim stam As String, comp As String
    Dim PathOnly As String, ijk As String, FileOnly As String
    Dim WsIjk As Worksheet, WsStam As Worksheet

    ijk = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    FileOnly = ThisWorkbook.Name
    PathOnly = Left(ijk, Len(ijk) - Len(FileOnly))
    stam = PathOnly & "\" & StBestand
    comp = PathOnly & "\" & Competenties

    Set WsIjk = ActiveSheet
    Set WbIjk = ThisWorkbook
    Set WbStambestand = Workbooks.Open(stam)
    Set WsStam = WbStambestand.Worksheets("stambestand")

    Dim rngOutput As Range
    Dim lastRowInput As Long

    Dim row As Long
    row = 2 'start row = 2
    Const colSelected As Long = 67, colPref1 As Long = 74, colPref2 As Long = 78, colPref3 As Long = 82
    'selected = BO = 67 (absolute column no.)
    'pref1 = BV = 74 (absolute column no.)
    'pref2 = BZ = 78 (absolute column no.)
    'pref3 = CD = 82 (absolute column no.)

    Set rngOutput = WsIjk.Range("A3") ' set start of output range; I'm using ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("A2") just as an example, modify it to your output workbook, output sheet, and start of output range
    With WsStam ' input data sheet; I'm using ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1) just as an example, modify it to your input workbook and input sheet
        lastRowInput = .Cells(.Rows.Count, colSelected).End(xlUp).row ' get last row of input range in column BO; I'm using the Worksheet.Cells(Worksheet.Rows.Count, "BO").End(xlUp).Row method; this is used in my loop termination condition (i.e. terminate when current row > lastRowInput)

        Debug.Print .Cells(row, colSelected).Value
        Do Until row > lastRowInput ' loop termination condition

            If .Cells(row, colSelected).Value <> "" Then ' output condition; you could of course use any more relevant condition, or remove this check entirely (if not having to deal with sparse rows)

                Select Case .Cells(row, colSelected).Value ' get the value of cell "BO#"
                    Case .Cells(row, colPref1).Value ' compare against the value of cell "BV#"
                        rngOutput.Value = 1
                    Case .Cells(row, colPref2).Value ' compare against the value of cell "BZ#"
                        rngOutput.Value = 2
                    Case .Cells(row, colPref3).Value ' compare against the value of cell "CD#"
                        rngOutput.Value = 3
                    Case Else
                        rngOutput.Value = 0
                End Select

                Set rngOutput = rngOutput(2) ' increment the output row

            End If
            row = row + 1 ' always increment the input row
        Loop

    End With

End Sub
```

This is a simple approach.

### Other solutions

#### Store column numbers as constants

Option two, but instead of using the actual relative column numbers throughout your code, you could store these constants. This is the method I would use if the structure might change and I wanted to prevent having to rewrite code.

#### All `rngInput` variables as a single Collection or similar

Similar to option three, but you could initialise some sort of iterable object (e.g. Collection, Array, Dictionary) of `rngInput`s, then cycle through them when: A) checking for matches*, and B).

*If using this method, you could also use a `Function` instead of `Select Case` or `If Then ElseIf` to check for matches.

This is the method I would use if I had many, or an indeterminate, number of input variables, and wanted to prevent rewriting code.

Comment: And if I were to put a counter/loop on the destination cell, so that it matches the row that the aforementioned loop uses. What would that look like?
cellaA1 as integer and then cellA1 +1 at the end?

Comment: the row number of the input is `row`; the row number of the output is written in the `Cells` method i.e. `WB2.Worksheets(1).Cells([output row number], "A")`; in this case `[output row number] = row - 1`

Comment: My preferred approach however is always to instantiate the Input Range and Output Range, then move each range with each loop (if appropriate to do so). I'll write up an example.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I'm getting stuck on `If rngInput(, "BO") <> "" Then` I see all the variables getting filled accordingly but everytime it skips the case part and goes to the end. 
I reckon it has something to do with the (, "BO") but I don't know why/how. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with `rngInput(, "BO")`; all this does is get the cell relative to `rngInput`: first parameter is the relative row, second parameter is relative column. In this case, first parameter is nothing, so it means "same row as `rngInput`", second parameter is "BO", so it means "column BO".

Comment: Note there are two subs: `Sub Test12` and `Sub Test34`; the latter doesn't have the `If rngInput(, "BO") <> "" Then` check. If it's failing to read `BO#`, try adding `Debug.Print rngInput.Address, rngInput(, "BO"), rngInput(, "BV"), rngInput(, "BZ"), rngInput(, "CD")` before `If rngInput(, "BO") <> "" Then` to make sure you can actually get some data. `rngInput.Address` should be `$A$2` to begin with.

Comment: Did you adapt your code from mine or did you copy it in full?

Comment: The printing results in the range adress of the input value. So `$BO$1, 2, 3, etc` So the input is ok. It's the checking that doesn't work. It skips the `then` argument: It basically reads If (for the first line, BO2) `If 2 <> " " then select case; else end If` It never enters the select case part and skipt to end If
For some reason 2 <> " " isn't true.

Comment: I'm not sure how much of a difference it will make (VBA can be odd this way), but try adding `.Value`, i.e. `If rngInput(, "BO").Value <> "" Then`; will update my answer as well.

Comment: If that doesn't sort it, can you upload your input data somewhere, e.g. you could save it as a CSV, open it with a text editor and upload the text content to the answer or pastebin or something

Comment: Hi, can you please provide the sample data?

Comment: Never mind, I've found your problem. Updated my answer.

Comment: It works (need to tweak some things, but you've given me the tools). Thanks a lot, you've been a huge help!

Answer (score 1):

If I understnad it correctly, you need to loop through the cells in "BO" and do some actions correspondingly. Thus, you need a loop and something to check the values and perform an action.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim cnt As Long

    For cnt = 2 To 5
        debug.print Range("BO" & cnt)
        stop 'uncomment it later
        Select Case Range("BO" & cnt)
            Case ("BV" & cnt)
                Range("A1") = 1
            Case ("BZ" & cnt)
                Range("A1") = 3
            Case Else
                MsgBox "Else"
        End Select
    Next cnt

End Sub
```

Try the code above and take a look at the cases. They can be edited easily. Try to see what you are getting in the immediate window, once you stop on the stop part of the code. Immediate window is opened with shortcut - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks @Vityata, I'll test it on monday. Hadn't head of the counter and cases before.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've tried it and I'm getting a result (which is a start) but all the output is the else case, so 0. Any idea why (I've edited the post to show your method)?

Comment: I did as you suggested. It prints out the value in `BO`. This changes when it goes to a different row number. However when it matches the cases, it always goes to the 'else'. So I get all zeroes (i changed msgbox to write 0 in a range). 
So almost there, just a tweak that I'm missing. Thoughts?